# "Variable names are limited to 10000 bytes" with gnm

Tags: r, gnm

I am using the `gnm` function in R. I am trying to fit a model with an integral portion which I have discretized by using six matrices whose columns are a binary indicator for that covariate at each time interval. Each of these columns is labelled with `a1, a2`, etc. for matrix 1, `b1, b2`, etc. for matrix 2, and so on. I have about 250 columns for each of these matrices.

I am passing these matrices to the gnm command as a string:

```
 mod<-gnm(as.formula(expr),family=binomial)
```

where `expr` is a character string that contains the list of all of the matrix column variable names (i.e., `a1, a2, ..., b1, b2, ....`).

My code produces sensible results when I use 5 matrices but when I try to use 6 matrices I get the following error when I try to run the `gnm` command.

```
 variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: `gnm` doesn't appear to be in base R, what library are you using? What exactly does `expr` look like? Is it formula-like (ie "y ~ a1 + a2 + ...")? Where is your data coming from? Problems are very hard to help with if you cannot provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `gnm(...)` is in package `gnm` - generalized nonlinear models.

Comment: I'm using `library(gnm)`. I'm not quite sure how to provide something that is reproducible but `expr` is of the form:
`expr<-paste0("cbind(y,1-y)~func1(",zlist")")`
where `func1` is a custom `nonlin` function (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf) and `zlist` is the string of the matrix column variable names (`"a1, a2,..."`)

Comment: `expr` will not be a formula, although I think you edited the question so now I could be wrong, but itis rather unclear at the moment).  Why not post an example with three small matrices? Then we can assess the risk of a "combinatorial explosion".

Comment: your variable names are too long `tmp <- paste(rep(letters[1:10], 1001), collapse = ''); assign(tmp, 1618)`. just post the code you are working with and any data to make it run, it's fairly straight-forward to provide a working example